# tflearn / tensorflow | Multi-stream/Multiscale/Ensemble model definition

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to define a multi-stream model with tflearn so that there are two copies of the same architecture (or you can think of it as an ensemble model) that I feed with different crops of the same image but not sure how I would go and implement that with tflearn.

I basically have this data:

```
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 : Dataset 1 (16images x 299 x 299px x 3ch)
X_train2, X_test2, y_train2, y_test2 : Dataset 2 (16images x 299 x 299px x 3ch)
```

And I have created so far this based on the `logical.py` [example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/basics/logical.py) (simplified code):

```
netIn1 = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 299, 299, 3]    
net1 = tflearn.conv_2d(netIn1, 16, 3, regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.0001)
...
net1 = tflearn.fully_connected(net1, nbClasses, activation='sigmoid')
net1 = tflearn.regression(net1, optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy')

netIn2 = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 299, 299, 3]    
net2 = tflearn.conv_2d(netIn2, 16, 3, regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.0001)
...
net2 = tflearn.fully_connected(net2, nbClasses, activation='sigmoid')
net2 = tflearn.regression(net2, optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

And then merge the two networks by concatenating:

```
net = tflearn.merge([net1, net2], mode = 'concat', axis = 1)
```

And start training like this:

```
# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net, checkpoint_path='model',
                max_checkpoints=10, tensorboard_verbose=3,
                clip_gradients=0.)

model.fit([X1,X2], [Y1,Y2], validation_set=([testX1, testX2], [testY1,testY2]))
```

So now my problem is how do I parse the inputs at the start of the network? How do I split the X1 to net1 and X2 to net2?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split X1 and X2, they will automatically be assigned to your input layers netIn1 and netIn2 (in the same order you define them).